# Fetch input type value by ID where display is not none

Tags: javascript, jquery, drupal

I have multiple fields associated with conditional select. If Condition doesn't match others input field get associated with style (display:none) in above div ID & one which match remains active, it set (display:block) in above div ID..
This is in drupal, so I don't have control over it...so here is the example which get generate--

```
<div id="edit-field-p1brp-price" class="field-type-text field-name-field-p1brp-price field-widget-text-textfield form-wrapper" style="display: block;">
  <div id="field-p1brp-price-add-more-wrapper">
    <div class="form-item form-type-textfield form-item-field-p1brp-price-und-0-value">
      <label for="edit-field-p1brp-price-und-0-value">
        <input id="edit-field-p1brp-price-und-0-value" class="text-full form-text required" type="text" maxlength="255" size="60" value="5,98,000" name="field_p1brp_price[und][0][value]">
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="edit-field-sspps-price" class="field-type-text field-name-field-sspps-price field-widget-text-textfield form-wrapper" style="display: none;">
  <div id="field-sspps-price-add-more-wrapper">
    <div class="form-item form-type-textfield form-item-field-sspps-price-und-0-value">
      <label for="edit-field-sspps-price-und-0-value">
      <input id="edit-field-sspps-price-und-0-value" class="text-full form-text required" type="text" maxlength="255" size="60" value="4,65,000" name="field_sspps_price[und][0][value]">
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
<div id="edit-field-sspr1br-price" class="field-type-text field-name-field-sspr1br-price field-widget-text-textfield form-wrapper" style="display: none;">
  <div id="field-sspr1br-price-add-more-wrapper">
    <div class="form-item form-type-textfield form-item-field-sspr1br-price-und-0-value">
      <label for="edit-field-sspr1br-price-und-0-value">
      <input id="edit-field-sspr1br-price-und-0-value" class="text-full form-text required" type="text" maxlength="255" size="60" value="3,98,000" name="field_sspr1br_price[und][0][value]">
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have to fetch the value of only that input for which DISPLAY is BLOCK in above DIV. I tried with the below DIV ID with visible, but it doesn't return & trying with above DIV ID and value for that also not happening(Here is the last code which I tried)--

```
if (($("#edit-field-p1brp-price-und-0-value:block").length > 0)){
  var price = $('#edit-field-p1brp-price-und-0-value').val();
}
if (($("#edit-field-sspps-price-und-0-value:visible").length > 0)){
  var price = $('#dit-field-sspps-price-und-0-value').val();
}
if (($("#edit-field-sspr1br-price-und-0-value:visible").length > 0)){
  var price = $('#edit-field-sspr1br-price-und-0-value').val();
}
```

UPDATE---

Code update which I am using for fetch the value on the change of one select & alert, but it's giving NULL only..

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        var price = null;
        $('div.form-item-field-membership-payment-type-und').change(function() {

          $("#edit-field-p1brp-price-und-0-value, #edit-field-sspps-price-und-0-value, #edit-field-sspr1br-price-und-0-value").each(function() {
                if($(this).is(':visible')) {
                    price = $(this).val();
                    alert(price);
                }
            });
        alert(price);   
    });  
    });
```

Comment: Shortening those IDs will reduce the total transfer size to the client side, thereby speeding up the page.

Comment: This is the way drupal render the form elements for conditional field...

Comment: Ahh, then theres nothing much you can do about it i believe. But if you look at the HTML you have posted, you will see that about 80% of the HTML payload is for the element IDs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use

```
$(selector).is(':visible')
```

Check out this jsfiddle, loops through your fields

http://jsfiddle.net/uuKHB/

**UPDATE**

I updated the jsfiddle for you:

http://jsfiddle.net/uuKHB/1/

```
$("#edit-field-p1brp-price-und-0-value, #edit-field-sspps-price-und-0-value, #edit-field-sspr1br-price-und-0-value").each(function() {
...
}
```

Now it loops through your inputs of choice (look at the selector, you can add multiple elements with comma seperation

**UPDATE TO ALERT**

```
var price;
$("#edit-field-p1brp-price-und-0-value, #edit-field-sspps-price-und-0-value, #edit-field-sspr1br-price-und-0-value").each(function() {
    if($(this).is(':visible')) {
        price = $(this).val();
    }
});
alert(price);
```

Like this ;)

Here's the updated jsfiddle with alert

http://jsfiddle.net/uuKHB/2/

Comment: I have other input type too on the page..I don't have to fetch their values

Comment: How can I alert the value which is inside the visible input id of all the listed ID which I am going through ? ?

Comment: This is working for me but I am trying var price = $(this).val(); & if I am trying to alert it outside...it doesn't give the value but inside it gives...I have to use the value outside...

Comment: make price outside of the loop "global". Then add the value to the variable price, then alert the price.. Should do the trick. I update my answer and the jsfiddle

Comment: I tried this..here is the jFiddle....inside alert gives value but outside it just give null value...http://jsfiddle.net/5KvDV/2/

Comment: It's because you reset var price inside the loop. I removed var (inside the loop) now it works: http://jsfiddle.net/5KvDV/3/

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23446/discussion-between-ferry-kobus-and-rajeevk)

Answer (score 0):

You are not setting display property and the default value of display would be inline-block. Set the display property to block if you need to check block or use inline-block in condition. You can use [css()](http://api.jquery.com/css/) to access display property. I suppose you have valid html and only one element has `id = edit-field-p1brp-price-und-0-value`

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/5KvDV/)**

```
if($("#edit-field-p1brp-price-und-0-value").css('display') == 'block')
{
    var price = $('#edit-field-sspr1br-price-und-0-value').val();
}
```

*If display is not block then else part will execute, this could be checked* [here](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/5KvDV/1/).

Comment: As you would see the display:none is the property of above DIV of the input type...doesn't worked..

Comment: You can debug to check what is going wrong or make a fiddle for us to find out what is going wrong.